# LiveData always returns LiveData<Object>?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to put a recyclerview which get its data from room. My function `getAllHomework` returns `LiveData<List<Homework>>`, but when I tried to set the return value to the recyclerview adapter, it will always return this error

```
Type Mismatch.
Required: List<Homework>
Found: List<Homework>?
```

Here's my HomeworkViewModel class which has the function `getAllHomework` looks like:

```
class HomeworkViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var matrixNumber: String? = null
    private var schoolID: Int = 0

    lateinit var listAllHomework: LiveData<List<Homework>>
    lateinit var homeworkRepository: HomeworkRepository

    fun init(params: Map<String, String>) {

        schoolID = Integer.parseInt(params["schoolID"])

        homeworkRepository = HomeworkRepository()
        listAllHomework = homeworkRepository.getAllHomework(1, "2018")

    }

    fun getAllHomework(): LiveData<List<Homework>>{
        return listAllHomework
    }
}
```

And below is the part in my Homework activity that tries to set the value into recyclerview adapter but will always return the type mismatch error.

```
class Homework : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleOwner {

    lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.homework)

        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvHomeworks.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        var adapter = AdapterHomework(this)

        rvHomeworks.adapter = adapter

        var homeworkViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeworkViewModel::class.java)
        homeworkViewModel.init(params)
        homeworkViewModel.getAllHomework().observe(this, Observer {
            allHomework -> adapter.setHomeworkList(allHomework)
        })
    }
}
```

The line `allHomework -> adapter.setHomeworkList(allHomework)` above will show the `Type Mismatch` error I mentioned above.

Here's how my `AdapterHomework` looks like:

```
class AdapterHomework(context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterHomework.ViewHolder>() {

lateinit var homeworkList: List<Homework>
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder{
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_homeworks, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @JvmName("functionToSetTheHomeworkList")
    fun setHomeworkList(myHomeworkList: List<Homework>){
        homeworkList = myHomeworkList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I could not find where in my code did I ever return `List<Homework>?` instead of `List<Homework>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has actually nothing to do with `Room`, but with how `LiveData` was designed - specifically `Observer` class:

```
public interface Observer<T> {

    void onChanged(@Nullable T t);
}
```

as you can see T (in your case `List<Homework>`) is marked as `@Nullable` therefore you will always get it's Kotlin equivalent `List<Homework>?` as a parameter of `onChanged` in your `Observer` implementation.

I would recommend changing `setHomeworkList` to something like this:

```
fun setHomeworkList(myHomeworkList: List<Homework>?){
    if(myHomeworkList != null){
        homeworkList = myHomeworkList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

You can also use `let` function for that like this:

```
fun setHomeworkList(myHomeworkList: List<Homework>?){
    myHomeworkList?.let {
        homeworkList = it
        notifyDataSetChanged() 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the explanation regarding the Observer class and the solution. This drove me crazy yesterday.